# Multiple Contexts using EF 6 duplicating tables in identity db and main db

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

This may be obvious but I'm missing it, so apologies if so.
I have a project using Entity Framework code first and all that good stuff.
I read that you should keep the Identity framework separate from the main DB so I created a separate context for it.
So far so good and even though there is a bit of additional complexity it isn't too much.

However, I want to reference the Address object from the main Identity User object (every user will have at least one), but there is a need for other addresses not related to users, but still addresses right? So they go in the main DB context.
I have added the Address class into the Identity model:

```
        public Address Address { get; set; }
```

This uses the Address class definition that is used in the 'MainDBcontext':

```
        public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
```

I add the migrations to set it all up but end up with an address table in both databases. Also I end up with different data in each Address table from the seed method depending if the Address is a user related one or not. Which makes sense I guess, but would really like all the addresses in one place. Yes, I guess I could just remove the address table from the 'MainDB' context and use the Identity one, but then I may as well move everything over ...

I am tempted just to move everything into one DB and have done with it but before I do, I wanted to see if there was a trick I'm missing.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd like to know why you "should" keep your identity and app context's separate? I've never done that and have not had any issues so far.

Comment: I'd agree with you and in the past I have kept them all together too, but I read it is considered best practice now... I'd like it to be wrong, or am at least agnostic. There is much discussion about this elsewhere and I'm just trying to solve the issue. I don't want this to be a debate about whether it really is best practice because I can't argue for it with conviction but at the time I was convinced.

Comment: I agree, this was news to me. I certainly need to do some reading up.

Comment: If you are going to relate to identity tables or vice versa it is best to have a single context that inherits from IdentityDbContext. You can't related classes in one context to another. Lots of hacks described where you can do joins or clones, etc. but KISS definitely applies here.

Comment: I agree and that is why this morning I modified it all to sit in one context inherited from Identitydb...
... also no answers to my actual question implies to me that it can't (easily) be done so... kiss and move on.. :)